How to get Visual Studio to behave like Visual Studio Code with sidebars?
Visual Studio Code's side panels are either open or closed. Crucially, when closed, there is still a sizeable icon or text to open it back up.
Visual Studio's side panels on the other hand are either closed (with no icon), always present ("pinned"), or auto-hide, where you have to click on it, and it overlaps other content and goes away when you click it. I don't like auto hide because it overlaps.
I really like VS Code's behavior on this - is there a way to get VS to behave this way? One possible compromise would be to use a shortcut to open something (e.g. Ctrl + ; for Solution Explorer) and then be able to easily close it.

@DanielB Is Zen Mode a thing for VS? I hadn't heard of it so when I searched I only got VS Code results.

Ah, sorry, I read your question the wrong way around.

I pin and unpin my Visual Studio panels to accomplish this, although pinning does take one more click than showing a Visual Studio Code panel.
